# how to get user name who created the file with du command

Tags: linux, users, disk-usage

We have a find command which displays the top 10 files occupied

```
$ find /root -type d -name "dummy" -prune -o -type f -exec du -a --time {} + | sort -n -r | head -n 10
1212     2018-11-01 08:35        File.txt
```

Is there any way to get the last updated name of the user who updated this file and size in MB/GB ?

Comment: You can simply use `ls -lh`.

Comment: actually i have a find command where i am trying to get top 10 huge space occupied files. In that case i am unable to get file user name who created the file..

Comment: please edit your question and add your actual command.

Comment: probably, `stat` is the better command for you.

Comment: @pLumo .. I have edit the question. Pls help me if any suggestion

Comment: I just noticed that the title says "created the file" but the question says "updated this file". That is a huge difference. You probably mean the latter as the first one is trivial.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what *the last updated name* is supposed to be but that probably doesn't matter as what you want is more or less impossible.

The Linux filesystems do not store the information which UID made the last change, just the time. So the information is not available in the filesystem at all.

The best approach is probably `autitd`, logging all write accesses in the system (that kind of approach does not make a system faster but you may log to a RAM disk (tmpfs)).

Answer (score 1):

`find` and return 10 biggest files, using `stat`:

```
find . \
-exec stat --printf '%s\t%y\t%U\t%n\0' {} + \
|  sort -rnz | head -zn10 | xargs -0 -n1
```

Comment: Thanks for the command , we have a case where we need to ignore "dummy" directory inside every master directory , by this will it be possible ?

Comment: sure, you should be able to just take your `find ...` command if that is working, and the rest from this answer.

Comment: i am unable to get expected output, can i ping the command here ?

Comment: If you have the command handy , can you help me to include here