# how to use find command on top of the output of ls

Tags: linux, grep, find, ls

I have below command which displays files/directories having `EXEC_EC`

command:

```
ls -ltr | grep 'EXEC_EC'
```

By using above command: Can we write a `find` command to filter the files created before 7 days?

I am trying to list the files having name `EXEC_EC` and trying to find the files older than 7 days.

Sample output

```
example input: 

dr-xr-xr-x   1 home abc       999 Jun 30 11:12 EXEC_EC_ABC_1
dr-xr-xr-x   1 home abc       999 Jul 25 12:44 EXEC_EC_ABC_2
dr-xr-xr-x   1 home abc       999 Aug  1 22:10 EXEC_EC_ABC_3
dr-xr-xr-x   1 home abc       999 Aug  2 22:20 Number
dr-xr-xr-x   1 home abc       999 Aug  2 22:20 Number2

i am trying to get below output 

EXEC_EC_ABC_1
EXEC_EC_ABC_2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not make sense to use `grep` for filtering if you use `find` anyway.

```
find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -name '*EXEC_EC*' -mtime +7
```

By default `find` traverses the whole subtree (i.e. the contents of all subdirectories). `-mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1` prevents that as the example works on the content of a single directory only. `-mindepth 1` makes `find` ignore the directory arguments (in this case, `.`, not necessary but in the general case). `-maxdepth 1` prevents descending into the subdirectories.

Comment: @ Thanks a lot Hauke for the reply . I have added sample output in my question.. Is this possible to get same output ? I tried this command but i am getting empty output

Comment: @Arya I removed the `-ls`. Should do as expected now.

Comment: @can i know what is meant by mindept /maxdepth and how it works.. (By this way this solution worked) :)

Comment: @Arya I added that information to the question.

Comment: @Thanks a lot Hauke. Can i ask one more doubt ?

Comment: @Arya This is a question site. Ask whatever you want to know. Everyone is free to answer, even in comments to an answer.

Comment: I have posted a question few days back 

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/600899/how-to-get-user-name-who-created-the-file-with-du-command/600902?noredirect=1#comment1121977_600902

but the answer didnt worked.. If possible can you help me with any suggestion for that

Answer (score 0):

This is what you are looking for ?

```
$ find . -name '*EXEC_EC*' -mtime +7 -print
```

. = Represent your current directory,you can replace that with a directory path .

-mtime - Represents the file modification time and is used to find files older than 7 days.

Comment: The question says *files/directories*. Your solution handles files only.

Comment: I added sample input/output in my question

Comment: Updated my answer . But i will go with @Hauke Laging as mindepth and maxdepth gives more accurate results.

Answer (score -2):

You don't need to pipe the output of ls into grep. Grep has a built in option for that.

```
grep -rle 'EXEC_EC'
```

-l will only list files
-r recursive means will go through all files starting from you current path
-e after this grep expects your pattern as a string

Comment: `-r` is **not** recursive with `ls`. Furthermore you mix up fire content with file name.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. but this doesn't works. I have some n number of files in one directory. Among then i required only files having name : 'EXEC_EC' and then on top of that i want to find all the  list of files older than 7 days.

Comment: @Hauke Laging. The author didn't specify he NEEDED to use ls for it. As you can read I said he doesn't need to pipe it.

Comment: Right but the example outputs the content of one directory without the subdirectories. Yours includes subdirectories. That is a severe problem (not the worst, though).